# In which order does java classloader load classes?

Tags: java, classloader

I have two libraries of different versions in classpath. Which version will classloader load? How could I change it?

Comment: The question is wrong. Locating the classes is very different from loading them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
lib-v1.jar:lib-v2.jar
```

then it's in order. `lib-v1.jar` will be loaded first (analogous to `PATH`).

I'd likely avoid this in practise (beyond uses for testing etc.) It can get confusing if you reference a library class in `lib-v2.jar` that's not in `lib-v1.jar` (possible if API's are retired). That way you'd load the *initial* class from v2, and further common classes from v1, and these may not be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on order in which you will provide this libraries list to JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Classloader has no information about your jar version. Generally You should avoid this kind of situations. You should hold the most recent version in your classpath